# upload large files to one drive for oneDrive iOS SDk?

Tags: swift, sdk, onedrive

Here i am stuck with my work because i can upload only small kb size file to one drive which is not enough. How can i upload large files to one drive using Sdk. Now i am using this sample project.
https://github.com/microsoftgraph/ios-swift-snippets-sample

Here uploading is shown only for Images and small size kb files to onedrive. How can we upload large files using Session?.

```
 func uploadFileToOneDrive(fileName : String,fileId : String, filePath : String){
    print("filePath \(filePath)")
    do {
        let fileData = try! Data(contentsOf: NSURL(fileURLWithPath: filePath) as URL)
        let fileLength = UInt64(fileData.count)
        print(fileLength)
        graphClient.me().drive().items(fileId + ":/createUploadSession").contentRequest().upload(from: fileData, completion: {
            (updatedItem, error) in
            if let nsError = error {
                self.delegate?.errorHandling(error: nsError.localizedDescription)
            }
            else {
                self.delegate?.Success(Sucess: NSLocalizedString("Uploaded", comment: ""))
                self.oneDriveListFiles(path: fileId, folderId: fileId, isBack: true)
            }

            print(self.progress.fractionCompleted)
        })
    }
}
```

also help me to do with the progressBar  for uploading and downloading?.

Answer (score 0):

Here is solution of both image upload and show download progress.AFNetworking library will used here:

```
- (void)uploadImageToServer{

    NSData *imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(_uploadImage, 0.5);

    NSString *urlString = @"<YOUR URL>;

    AFHTTPSessionManager *manager = [AFHTTPSessionManager manager];

 manager.requestSerializer = [AFJSONRequestSerializer serializer];
    manager.responseSerializer = [AFHTTPResponseSerializer serializer];
    [manager.requestSerializer setValue:@"application/x-www-form-urlencoded" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
    [manager POST:urlString parameters:_param constructingBodyWithBlock:^(id<AFMultipartFormData>  _Nonnull formData) {

        [formData appendPartWithFileData:imageData name:@"uploaded_file" fileName:@"uploaded_file.jpg" mimeType:@"image/jpeg"];

    } progress:^(NSProgress * _Nonnull uploadProgress) {
        [manager setTaskDidSendBodyDataBlock:^(NSURLSession *session, NSURLSessionTask *task, int64_t bytesWritten, int64_t totalBytesWritten, int64_t totalBytesExpectedToWrite) {
            float processbar = (float)totalBytesWritten / (float)totalBytesExpectedToWrite;
            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue( DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_LOW, 0), ^{
                //do something
                dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                    _progressView.progress = processbar;
                    _lblProgressPercentage.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.0f%%",(processbar*100)];

                });
                //do something else
            });
        }];

    } success:^(NSURLSessionDataTask * _Nonnull task, id  _Nullable responseObject) {


    } failure:^(NSURLSessionDataTask * _Nullable task, NSError * _Nonnull error) {
        NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);

    }];
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the comments. Actually i need to upload large .pdf file not actually images. now i am using onedrive SDK. And I need swift code :)